# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (No Inheritence)

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

Although there are several people who seem to have answered this question, but they are often refering to inheritance. I recieve the error: `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` when I run this segment:

```
class game:
    def __init__(self):
        global drawPile  
        self.x = 1
        drawPile = deck(playerCount)
```

of this code:

```
# Modules #
import random, time, termcolor
from os import system

# Functions ##
def clear(wait=0):
    time.sleep(wait)
    _ = system("clear")

"""
def cp(string, color=None, on_color=None, attrs=None):
    cprint(termcolor.colored(string,color,on_color,attrs))
"""     
def cprint(string, color= "magenta"):
    print(termcolor.colored(string, color))

def ans(x = ">>| ", color = "cyan"):
    return input(termcolor.colored(x, color))

cprint("How many players are there")
playerCount = int(ans())

class deck:
    def __init__(self):
        global player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6, playerlist
        if playerCount == 2:
            embasy = 0
            player1 = player(1)
            player2 = player(2)
            playerlist = [player1, player2]
        elif playerCount == 3:
            embasy = 0
            player1 = player(1)
            player2 = player(2)
            player3 = player(3)
            playerlist = [player1, player2, player3]
        elif playerCount == 4:
            embasy = 1
            player1 = player(1)
            player2 = player(2)
            player3 = player(3)
            player4 = player(4)
            playerlist = [player1, player2, player3, player4]
        elif playerCount == 5:
            embasy = 2
            player1 = player(1)
            player2 = player(2)
            player3 = player(3)
            player4 = player(4)
            player5 = player(5)
            playerlist = [player1, player2, player3, player4, player5]
        elif playerCount == 6:
            embasy = 3
            player1 = player(1)
            player2 = player(2)
            player3 = player(3)
            player4 = player(4)
            player5 = player(5)
            player6 = player(6)
            playerlist = [player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, player6]
        playerlist = playerlist
        self.set = [["embasy"] * embasy, ["diplomat (-1)"]*10, ["master spy (-5)"] * 10, ["celebrity 5"] * 10, ["investigate"] * 10, ["embargo"] * 10, ["safe house"] *10, ["embargo"] * 10, ["counterintellegence"] * 10, ["jail cell"] * 10, ["college student (1)"] * 10, ["family (3)"] * 10, ["spy (-3)"] * 10]
        self.cards = []
        for i in self.set:
            for j in i:
                self.cards.append(j)
        self.cards = random.sample(self.cards, len(self.cards))

    def deal(self):
        for j in range(5):
            for i in playerlist:
                i.drawCard(self.cards.pop(0))





class player:
    def __init__(self, number):
        embasy = [False, []]
        self.otherPlayers = []
        for i in range(1, start.drawPile.playerCount + 1):
            self.otherPlayers.append(number)
        self.otherPlayers.remove(number)
        self.hand = []
        self.leftPile = []
        self.rightPile = []
        self.embasyPile = []
        self.jailPiles = [0, []]

    def drawCard(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)

    def playCard(self, card):
        self.hand.remove(card)

    def recieveCard(self, card, pile):
        if pile == "left":
            self.leftPile.append(card)
        elif pile == "right":
            self.leftPile.append(card)
        elif pile == "embasy":
            self.leftPile.append(card)
        elif pile == "jail":
            self.jailPiles[2].append(card)

    def playTurn(self):
        clear(3)
        cprint("In your hand you have:")
        for i in self.hand:
            cprint(f"\t{i}")
        time.sleep(2)
        cprint("Which would you like to play?")
        card = ans()
        if card not in self.hand:
            self.playTurn()
        if card == "embasy":
            pass



class game:
    def __init__(self):
        global drawPile  
        self.x = 1
        drawPile = deck(playerCount)

start = game()
```

I apologize if I put to much of my program.

Comment: Please share syntax how you are calling/executing this code. trackback may give additional clue.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the deck constructor you are trying to pass an argument, in this line:

```
drawPile = deck(playerCount)
```

But you declare the deck constructor as taking no argument, except self:

```
class deck:
    def __init__(self):
```

That's what Python is complaining about, but the actual text of the error message is confusing to beginners.  Since deck is a class and not a function, Python automatically adds a first argument, self, to the constructor call.  That's why the error message says "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given."  The error message counts "self" as one argument.  Since you tried to supply another one, that means "two were given."

Answer (score 1):

Your `playerCount` variable is global, so you don't need to pass it as argument, when creating the `deck` object. So simply replace the class `game` with the following lines:

```
class game:
    def __init__(self):
        global drawPile  
        self.x = 1
        drawPile = deck()
```